# How can I pass the value from a view to another view in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
    import UIKit

    class TableController: UITableViewController {

    var items = NSMutableArray()
    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var json:String = ""

    var quantity2: Int = 0
    var shortDate: String = ""

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
    var arrayOfMenu: [Nutrisi] = [Nutrisi]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpMenu()
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfMenu.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell
        let menu = arrayOfMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(menu.type, rightlabeltext: menu.unit, imagename: menu.image)
        var data = Nutritiondata(type: menu.type, amount: String(cell.value).toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        self.json = json
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func do_table_refresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }

    func setUpMenu()
    {

        var json: JSON = JSON (data: NSData())
        let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 110, y: 300, width: view.frame.width, height: 700)
        self.tableView.frame = frame
        DataManager.getnutritionsDataFromFileWithSuccess{ (data) -> Void in
            json = JSON(data: data)
            let results = json["results"]
            for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < json["nutritions"].count; i++) {
                if let type = json["nutritions"][i]["type"].string {
                    if let icon: AnyObject = json["nutritions"][i]["icon"].string {
                        self.items.addObject(icon)
                        if let unit = json["nutritions"][i]["unit"].string {

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView!.reloadData()})
var menu = Nutrisi(type: type, unit: unit, image: icon as! String)
                                    self.arrayOfMenu.append(menu)
                                    self.TableData.append(type + unit )
                                    self.do_table_refresh();               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've this code, and works well on table controller view, but I want to make a new view controller that prints `json` (`json` on table controller works well, and printed out)

So, I made a new view controller connected to another class named `senddata` what command that I should use to print `json` on there, I want to print that `json` data when the button pressed:

```
import UIKit

class SendData: UIViewController{

    @IBAction func tes(sender: AnyObject) {
        println()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put that JSON Data in a global struct, so it would end up looking like this.

TableViewController.swift

```
struct JSON {
  static var JSONData = ""
}

  class TableController: UITableViewController {

    var items = NSMutableArray()
    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var json:String = ""

    var quantity2: Int = 0
    var shortDate: String = ""

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
    var arrayOfMenu: [Nutrisi] = [Nutrisi]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpMenu()
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfMenu.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell
        let menu = arrayOfMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(menu.type, rightlabeltext: menu.unit, imagename: menu.image)
        var data = Nutritiondata(type: menu.type, amount: String(cell.value).toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        JSON.JSONData = json
        return cell
    }
```

SendData.swift

```
class SendData: UIViewController{

    @IBAction func tes(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(JSON.JSONData)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Comment: it says json.type doesn't have a member called jsondata .. :(

Comment: No Problem, could you accept my answer as the correct answer?

Comment: You could also use the prepareForSegue method().

Comment: Good Point, but I didn't know the segue identifier.