# How do I pass data between two scenes in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have two scenes where I would like to pass a single variable to another scene using a segue. I have tried but unfortunately all tutorials I have seen are dealing with the storyboard. I am not using the storyboard.  I am doing all of this programatically.

Here is the segue i am trying to initialize:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
        var lose = segue.destinationViewController as! loserScene;

        lose.toPass = scoreLabelNode.text

    }
}
```

The Loser Scene is my second scene.
scoreLabelNode.text is the text of an NSTimer which i'm using as a score.

I want to move the scoreLabelNode.text into another scene which is my loserScene.

My loserScene is set up like this:

```
    import SpriteKit
import Foundation

let GameOverLabelCategoryName = "gameOverLabel"

class loserScene: SKScene {
    var toPass: String!
    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"[z] Arista Light")



    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var gameOver = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gameover.png")
        gameOver.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(gameOver)
        println(toPass)




    }
}
```

I am trying to print 'toPass' to test the string segue, but I just get nil.

Comment: Long story short, I need to be able to programmatically pass data to another scene without the use of a storyboard.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737746/how-can-i-pass-the-value-from-a-view-to-another-view-in-ios/31737790#31737790

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK! So instead of using a segue. WHICH YOU CANNOT DO WITH AN SKSCENE. I used a struct.  I put the struct outside of one of my scenes that I wanted data to be passed from, and made sure the data was being fed into the struct. I then accessed the struct from another scene and it works perfectly!

```
struct Variables {
static var aVariable = 0
}
```

this is the struct^ I have it set to 0 but it will be updated automatically when the score is recorded at the end of the run of my game.
I then accessed it like so in another scene:

```
print(Variables.aVariable)
```

This prints the variable from the struct in my new scene. I can also turn this struct into a string and use it for a labelnode.

Comment: I used a similar approach. Instead of using a structure, only one static variable in the target ViewController file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your toPass String returns nil because **it is not initialized** when you send the value from your prepareForSegue method.

Create a some function for example;

```
// Do whatever you need with the toPass variable.
func printToPassValue(){
     print(toPass)
}
```

And add the property observers to your toPass variable. like this;

```
var toPass: String? {
    willSet {
     printToPassValue() // Call your function
     }
}
```

And add this function to your viewDidLoad method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        printToPassValue()
}
```

Comment: unfortunately still returns nil.  I may have to take a different approach to passing variables

Comment: I am using an SKScene which doesn't allow segue's so I will have to redo all of this