# Swift 2 Struct with Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, static

I am new to Swift and to making games (as well as fairly new to coding in general), I currently want to pass a variable between two `Gamescene`s. After doing some research I have come to the conclusion I require a `struct` with a `[int]()` to hold the numbers I want for some reason while I am not able to assign values into the my integer array `generatedSequenceArray` 
my Struct:

```
struct generatedSequenceForGameScene {
     static var generatedSequenceArray = [Int]()
}
```

In my one of my `GameScene` classes I have initialized my `generatedSequenceForGameScene` `struct` object:

```
var generatedSequence = generatedSequenceForGameScene()
```

The method I am calling on is:

```
func pickNumbers(){

    for var x = 0; x < highLevel; ++x{
        generatedSequence.generatedSequenceArray.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
        print(generatedSequence.generatedSequenceArray)

   }
}
```

Before attempting to have a variable move from each `GameScene` my code was this:

Variable:
  `var generatedSequence = [Int]()`

Method:

func pickNumbers(){

```
    for var x = 0; x < highLevel; ++x{
    generatedSequence.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    print(generatedSequence)

    }
}
```

This gave me my desired results.
NOTE: The `pickNumber` method gets called in a method named `loadView()` which is placed in the `didMoveToView` method in the program

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to note here.

First, the `static` keyword inside your struct makes `generatedSequenceArray` a static property. This means it'll be the same everywhere you call it. This isn't what you want.

Second, unless you plan to add more properties to your struct, there's no reason for it to exist. Why wrap it in a struct at all? Why not just pass the array of integers (your picked numbers) directly?

Third, type names should be proper case. So `generatedSequenceForGameScene` should be `GeneratedSequenceForGameScene`).

Comment: The reason why I am using a `static` variable is because I want it to be everywhere. The purpose is so that I can pass this array of integers to a different scene where it can do other things. Also I found this example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290460/how-do-i-pass-data-between-two-scenes-in-swift) 

Also I do not know any other way of passing a variable or array to a separate scene file. (I am not using the storyboard at all) 

Thank you for my mistake about the proper casing though I will be sure to fix it

Comment: No. No, no no no no. :-D If you want to pass something between controllers, make sure you make and keep references from one controller for the next *or* create a singleton that can be accessed from anywhere, which generates and serves the common data. Yours is an improper use of `static`. As I said before, this is *not* what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I have heard the term singleton before (I know its an instance of a class that can only be made once) but I do not know how to use it (in swift or anywhere else) how would I go about making it and using it? (I am not using controllers but child classes of 'SKScene's I have made (before I called them `GameScene` on accident (sorry))

Comment: Give this a read: https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/ (first the pattern is given in ObjC, then in Swift) ...the idea in your case would be to make some game manager object that generates and makes available your game data from wherever by calling something like `GameManager.sharedInstance.gameSequence` (where `gameSequence` is a property of `GameManager`).

Comment: I assume I just place all my methods and variables underneath the `static let sharedInstance`. I am still getting another issue, the `SKScene` that I am making with the singleton gets runs at when the game starts. When I try to use my "Sequence" variable in another seen the Sequence(array is empty) even though when I run my first `SKScene` the "Sequence" variable contains elements this is my [comparison method](https://gyazo.com/178806141b3f817b5b6e550297a4959c)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly isn't working for you.  I guess you're having trouble sharing a sequence from one game scene to another.  If that's the problem, maybe the following helps:

```
struct Sequence {
    var seqArray = [Int]()

    mutating func pickNumbers() {

        for var x = 0; x < 10; ++x {
            seqArray.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
        }
        print( "picked: \(seqArray)" )
    }
}

class GameScene {
    var s = Sequence()
}

var g1 = GameScene()
var g2 = GameScene()

g1.s.pickNumbers()
g2.s.seqArray = g1.s.seqArray

print( g2.s.seqArray )
```

Comment: I do not want to make a `GameScene` objects, also I seem to have made a mistake by `GameScene`(Sorry) I mean something that is a child of `SKScene`. In my program I would like one the child `SKScene`'s to generate a sequence of random Integers based on the level that the user is currently at `x < highestLevel` I would like to then transfer the same array to another `SKScene` so that I may continue using it. (Also I would like my variable `highestLevel` to be the same for every `SKScene` and the device should remember it. (I believe NSUserDefaults)

Comment: If you want two variables, `highestLevel` and a `Sequence` to be the same across all uses in the app, then make them global variables.

Comment: When you say 'the device should remember it', it sounds like you want to look for SO (StackOverflow) answers that match the search `NSUserDefaults persist`.